# VictoriaMetrics / Grafana - daily metric aggregate shows correct results but shifted by two days

Tags: prometheus, grafana, home-assistant, victoriametrics

I'm using HomeAssistant with Tasmota smart plugs to collect energy usage data.

The smart plugs report a total energy counter metric and I aggregate them all in HomeAssistant and feed into VictoriaMetrics as a single "total_energy" metric. I plot the graphs with Grafana. Since the metric is of a counter type, I'm using the `increase` rollup function to plot daily energy usage.

```
increase(kWh_value{entity_id="total_energy"})
```

This works fine except for the fact that my results are shifted on the X axis by two days forward. I manually checked that the measurement point for a given day is actually a measurement for two days before.

To work around this I applied an offset to my query:

```
increase(kWh_value{entity_id="total_energy"}) offset -2d
```

Here's a screenshot  with two graphs. The top one's query is `increase(kWh_value{entity_id="total_energy"}) offset -2d` and it's showing correct values. The bottom one is just `increase(kWh_value{entity_id="total_energy"})`.
[image: screenshot]

While the workaround works, it just feels wrong and I'm puzzled what I did incorrectly. I checked the sensor data fed into VictoriaMetrics and it seems to have correct timestamps.

EDIT:

Following hagen1778's recommendation I inspected raw samples of my VictoriaMetrics db. At 10:15 AM GMT+01:00 time I ran

```
curl http://homeassistant:8428/api/v1/export -d 'match[]=kWh_value{entity_id="total_energy"}' -d 'start=-1h' -d 'end=now' | jq
```

Results:

```
{
  "metric": {
    "__name__": "kWh_value",
    "db": "home_assistant",
    "domain": "sensor",
    "entity_id": "total_energy"
  },
  "values": [
    47.877,
    47.878,
    47.879,
    47.88,
    47.881,
    47.883,
    47.884,
    47.886,
    47.887,
    47.888,
    47.89,
    47.892,
    47.893,
    47.895,
    47.897,
    47.899,
    47.9,
    47.902,
    47.903,
    47.904,
    47.905,
    47.906,
    47.907,
    47.909,
    47.91,
    47.912,
    47.913,
    47.915,
    47.916,
    47.917,
    47.919,
    47.92,
    47.922,
    47.923,
    47.925,
    47.926,
    47.928,
    47.929,
    47.93,
    47.931,
    47.932,
    47.933,
    47.935,
    47.936,
    47.938,
    47.939,
    47.94,
    47.942,
    47.943,
    47.946,
    47.947,
    47.949,
    47.95,
    47.952,
    47.954,
    47.955,
    47.957,
    47.958,
    47.959,
    47.961,
    47.962,
    47.964,
    47.965,
    47.967,
    47.968,
    47.97,
    47.971,
    47.973,
    47.974,
    47.975,
    47.977,
    47.978,
    47.98,
    47.981,
    47.982,
    47.984,
    47.985,
    47.987,
    47.989,
    47.991,
    47.992,
    47.993,
    47.995,
    47.996,
    47.998,
    47.999,
    48.001,
    48.002,
    48.004,
    48.005,
    48.006,
    48.007,
    48.009,
    48.01,
    48.012,
    48.014,
    48.016,
    48.017,
    48.019,
    48.02,
    48.022,
    48.023,
    48.024,
    48.026,
    48.027,
    48.029,
    48.031,
    48.032,
    48.034,
    48.035,
    48.037,
    48.038,
    48.04,
    48.042,
    48.044,
    48.045,
    48.047,
    48.049,
    48.051,
    48.052,
    48.054,
    48.055,
    48.056
  ],
  "timestamps": [
    1694852252610,
    1694852280277,
    1694852461135,
    1694852520226,
    1694852531135,
    1694852581175,
    1694852589131,
    1694852641198,
    1694852701151,
    1694852703193,
    1694852761146,
    1694852821153,
    1694852875408,
    1694852881200,
    1694852941174,
    1694853001145,
    1694853011677,
    1694853061174,
    1694853070434,
    1694853071445,
    1694853121209,
    1694853123251,
    1694853131446,
    1694853181181,
    1694853191454,
    1694853241183,
    1694853251465,
    1694853301162,
    1694853311460,
    1694853325450,
    1694853361190,
    1694853371474,
    1694853421183,
    1694853431471,
    1694853481180,
    1694853491475,
    1694853541190,
    1694853550466,
    1694853551475,
    1694853572662,
    1694853601157,
    1694853611476,
    1694853661190,
    1694853671489,
    1694853721180,
    1694853731488,
    1694853775481,
    1694853781190,
    1694853791461,
    1694853841163,
    1694853851467,
    1694853901134,
    1694853911473,
    1694853961130,
    1694853971478,
    1694853992647,
    1694854021161,
    1694854031483,
    1694854060475,
    1694854081149,
    1694854091488,
    1694854141173,
    1694854151495,
    1694854201167,
    1694854210498,
    1694854261151,
    1694854271507,
    1694854321170,
    1694854331510,
    1694854350137,
    1694854381143,
    1694854390498,
    1694854441144,
    1694854443159,
    1694854450510,
    1694854501145,
    1694854511520,
    1694854561149,
    1694854571531,
    1694854621177,
    1694854630535,
    1694854635142,
    1694854681150,
    1694854690544,
    1694854741187,
    1694854750554,
    1694854801165,
    1694854810531,
    1694854861136,
    1694854863153,
    1694854870551,
    1694854895142,
    1694854921164,
    1694854930553,
    1694854981169,
    1694854990560,
    1694855041177,
    1694855050566,
    1694855100233,
    1694855110571,
    1694855161183,
    1694855170582,
    1694855180142,
    1694855220226,
    1694855230583,
    1694855280269,
    1694855290592,
    1694855312670,
    1694855341157,
    1694855350596,
    1694855401144,
    1694855410600,
    1694855461190,
    1694855470610,
    1694855521158,
    1694855530606,
    1694855581178,
    1694855590596,
    1694855641130,
    1694855650603,
    1694855701140,
    1694855710607,
    1694855725613
  ]
}
```

The last timestamp `1694855725613` translates to 10:15:25.613 AM GMT+01:00, which seems correct. Data seems fine (at least for the last hour).

Another update is that in Grafana I switched the time zone to UTC and the shift is no longer 2 days, but 1 day only. It's still required though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend following default guide for unexpected query results in VictoriaMetrics here https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Troubleshooting.html#unexpected-query-results

Would be nice if you can find a one specific time series which is shifted by 2d on your graph and export its raw data as graph suggests. In this way we can verify its timestamps are actually correct.

Comment: Thanks @hagen1778, I updated the post following your guideline. Let me know if that's what you had in mind.

Comment: adding `-d 'end=now'` filters the data, returning datapoints with timestamps `<=now()`.  If we want to verify that VM doesn't hold timestamps in future - we should update `end=+48h` param.

Comment: Good point! However, `end=+48h` fails with invalid numeric literal. I guess the '+' sign isn't valid. Anyway, I tried putting a date that's few days in the future, so simply `end=2023-09-22` and the last timestamp corresponds to the time when I made the query, so my VM doesn't hold timestamps in the future.

Comment: Thanks for checking! It is a bit weird, maybe timezone in Grafana is shifted in a weird way. Or Grafana itself is installed on instance with shifted time. 

Negative offset means querying data from the future.Try it on VM playground https://play.victoriametrics.com/select/accounting/1/6a716b0f-38bc-4856-90ce-448fd713e3fe/prometheus/graph

1. Enter a query, i.e. `sum(up)`

2. Then add `offset -15m`

You'll see that right half of the graph is empty because VM doesn't have data in the future.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, you're right that in vm playground it behaves correctly. I also realized that this offset is only necessary when I increase the `Min interval` in Grafana Query Options from default to something like 1hr or 1d. When it's small like 15s there's no offset needed. But I want that interval to be 1d, because I'm interested in plotting daily energy usage. Maybe I'm misunderstanding how this option is meant to be used.